# Subscript in beamer class using frames and equations

Tags: beamer, math-mode, subscripts

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
    Energy Factor_A_big/small 
  \end{equation}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to achieve there is to get a space in between `Energy` and `Factor`, secondly. I want `A` to be a subscript of `Energy Factor` and `big/small` to be a subscript of `A`.

What is the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: OK. Spacing is solved `\,` did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is quite nasty, but `Energy~Factor_{A_{big/small}}` does the job. In my opinion `\text{Energy Factor}_{A_\text{big/small}}` is way better.